# jQuery draggable helper position

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to change possition of a draggable helper position, just on the start of dragging, so the grid will be counted on the new position of a draggindg element.

Dragging element change its width on the start (start dragging) and it doesn't 'fit in' the grid [100x100].

> ```
> start: function (event, ui) {
>     ui.helper.css("width", '102px');
> }
> ```

Here is example : http://jsfiddle.net/sYHre/73/

as you can see on the example blue element perfectly fit grid, but red one is not. I tried to change its position on the fly but that does't work (commented out code), object is jumping, i think it's kind of bug in jquery ui. Maybe there is better way to do this?

Im using newest jQuery and jQuery UI 1.9.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element's width is changing once you start dragging because it was originally of class `two`, which is `width: 51px`, but your `start` function changes it to `ui.helper.css("width", '102px')` once you start dragging. If you don't want its width to change, take that line out - it's not doing anything other than changing the width of that item. If you *do* want the width to change width but without the "jumpiness" you could animate the change to make it more smooth - `ui.helper.animate({width: 102}, 500)` seems to work okay. Even that's a little disorienting, though - I'd advise against changing the width at all unless there's a reason I'm not seeing to do so.

The object doesn't fit the grid because class `two` calls for it to be at `left: 50%`, which won't line up perfectly with your 100 x 100 grid. If you want it lined up with the grid, you can have it line up by changing that to `left: 504px` instead.

If, on the other hand, you want it to start at `left: 50%` but then, once you start dragging, snap to the nearest corner, you want to add `snap: '.target'` to your list of options. That will force it to snap to the grid even if it doesn't start out lined up with the grid. (In fact, if you prefer, you can set `snapTolerance: 100`, in which case you don't even need a grid - the draggable objects will always snap to the target objects.)

[Here's an updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sYHre/85/) that shows the use of `snap`. [This is the same fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sYHre/84/), but with the width change animated so you can see how that works.

I hope this answered your question. If not, please try to explain again exactly what you're trying to achieve.